# No such property: currentperson for class: kaf82.portal.PersonsController

Tags: grails

Here the controller's code:

```
package kaf82.portal

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory

class PersonsController {
    def personList = []
    String personsFile = new File('media/data/personsData.xml').text   

    def allpersons () {
        def persons = new XmlParser().parseText(personsFile)
        [persons: persons]        
    }    

    def currentperson () {        
        int id=params.id.toInteger()    
        getPersons()
        [currentperson=personList.get(id-1)]       
    }

    def getPersons() {
        def builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
        def inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(personsFile.bytes)
        def root  = builder.parse(inputStream).documentElement        
        def persons = root.childNodes
        (0..<persons.length).each{ processPerson(persons.item(it)) }
        ...
```

I'm using Grails 2.4.4.

Here is stacktrace

```
 Line | Method
->>   17 | currentperson in PersonsController.groovy
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    198 | doFilter      in PageFragmentCachingFilter.java
|     63 | doFilter . .  in AbstractFilter.java
|     53 | doFilter      in GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java
|     49 | doFilter . .  in RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java
|     82 | doFilter      in MutableLogoutFilter.java
|   1142 | runWorker . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run           in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: `(0..<persons.length).each{ processPerson(persons.item(it)) }` would just be `persons.each{ processPerson it }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming the line 17 is:

```
[currentperson=personList.get(id-1)]
```

you did not initialize the map correctly (see [groovy docs](http://www.groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#Collections-Maps)). The correct solution would be:

```
[currentperson: personList.get(id-1)]
```

otherwise the compiler things there should be a variable `currentperson` that you want to assign a value to it.

Comment: Thank you for help and documentation too.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a map with `[currentperson=personList.get(id-1)]`, but this syntax is wrong.

```
[currentperson: personList.get(id-1)]
```

Also this `personList` as a property looks wrong.